# how can I match on a datum?

Tags: racket

I'd like to write a pattern that only matches on a single datum like `'a` or `'hello` but not anything else. I don't think the following works as it matches on everything (like `(list 1 2 3)`)right?

```
(define (f x)
  (match x (e (printf "hi~n"))))
```

Comment: Racket doesn’t really have any well-defined notion of an “atom” in the sense that some other systems do, so there is probably no built-in predicate that does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datums can be used as patterns. Here is an example:

```
#lang racket

(define (f x)
  (match x
    ["hello" "x is hello"]
    [_       "x is not hello"]))

(f "hello")
(f 42)
```

The result is:

```
"x is hello"
"x is not hello"
```

Also if you want to use a fixed symbol as a pattern use `'hello` and not just `hello`. The first `'hello` matches a single symbol but `hello` is a pattern variable and matches everything.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to write a pattern that catches "all symbols" not just a particular fixed one though. so one that catches '42 'hello and the like but not anything else.

Comment: In that case use `(? symbol? sym)` to match a symbol and bind the result of a match to sym.